# Reading values from opened desktopapplication windows

Tags: c#, java, winforms

I'm developing a web framework which needs to interact with a desktop application. The desktop application can vary between companies. For instance when a user logs in using the desktop application, the username should be send to the browser (for instance using get).

Is there something available that can read windows? For instance created in Windows Forms, Java Swing or other frameworks?

I only found AutoIT which can read the titlebar but we'd also like to read values from textboxes, checkboxes, comboboxes, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i have asked similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015143/how-to-capture-text-using-mouse-pointer-and-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it you need something like `Pipes`. You can use Pipes to pass information between applications.